# weakly amenable weighted sequence algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, banach-algebras, amenability

Let $v=(v_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a positive weight with $\inf_nv_n>0$ (for convenience we may take $v_n\geqslant1$). Then $\ell_{\infty}(v)$ is a Banach algebra with coordinate-wise multiplication. Is it weakly amenable?

Comment: Isn't $\ell_\infty(v)$ a von Numann algebra? All von Numann algebras are weakly amenable.

Comment: @MeisamSoleimaniMalekan It isn't a von Neumann algebra because it has a different norm.

Comment: To the OP: can you clarify if your norm is defined by $\sup_n |x_n| \nu_n$ or $\sup_n |x_n| \nu_n^{-1}$?

Comment: I am terribly sorry for not responding so long - I feel ahamed. The norm in $\ell_{\infty}(v)$ is $\sup_n|x_n|v_n$. To be honest, I forgot I posted this question and some time ago I found the answer (hopefully). I don't know whether or not it's polite to present a self-answer so I stop at the moment.

Comment: @Krzysztof, its fine. I would like to know the answer!

Comment: @Norbert, if $(v_n)_n$ is bounded then $\ell_{\infty}(v)$ is isomorphic (as a Banach algebra) to $\ell_{\infty}$ (recall $\inf_nv_n>0$) and so even amenable. Assume now $v$ is an unbounded weight. Wlog let $v$ diverge to infinity. Consider (this is a result of my discussion with Mateusz Wasilewski and Mikolaj Fraczyk) a functional $\phi$ on $\ell_{\infty}(v)$ defined as $\phi(x):=\lim_{\mathcal{U}}x_nv_n$ over a free ultrafiler $\mathcal{U}$ on $\mathbb{N}$. It is continuous, it vanishes on $\overline{\ell_{\infty}(v)^2}$ and $\phi(v^{-1})=1$.

Comment: Thus $v^{-1}\in\ell_{\infty}(v)\setminus\overline{\ell_{\infty}(v)^2}$. This means that the algebra $\ell_{\infty}(v)$ is not essential and this is a weaker condition than weak amenability -- see Theorem 2.8.63 in Dales' monograph "Banach Algebras and Automatic Continuity". Consequently, if $\ell_{\infty}(v)$ is an algebra then it is either amenable or not weakly amenable.